# How do I get the index of an item which has been removed from a list?

Tags: python

Is there a function that can get the index of a removed item?
The `remove()` function returns nothing.
Do I need to write a function by myself or there is a built-in one?

Answer (score 1):

If an element is removed from a list, it is not in the list any more, and thus does not have an index.

If you mean the index the element had before the removal, then just do it in two steps:

```
lst = [2, 4, 7]
el = 4

# find the element's index
ix = lst.index(el)

# delete the element
del lst[ix]

print(lst)
# => [2, 7]
print(ix)
# => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to remove an item and return its index but you can get the index of an item using the `.index("example")` method.

You can then use the same value you used previously to `.remove("example")` the value or the other possible method that's already not been listed. Is using `.pop()` and the index you get as a return from the `.index()` method. Using the pop method will return the value at that index after successfully removing it.

Comment: As OP correctly pointed out already, that's NOT what `remove` does.

Comment: You want `del`, not `remove`

Comment: `.pop` will work though. I chose not to use `.pop` since it returns the element's value — but if you are starting off with the value, it is unneeded overhead.

Comment: @Amadan You have a valid point there though. I will make some edits to make it more clear.